# Should I artificially slow down POSTing data

Tags: python, post

I have a Python program that runs on a local machine, gathers information, and then sends it to a Spring backend.

Here is my Python code that sends all the information created in a temp file

```
for line in dumpFile:
line = line.strip("\n")
sender = line.split("&")
if sender[0] == 'NONE':
    sw_send_url = url + "/device/addProgram"
    data = {
        "customerId" : 1L,
        "deviceId" : DEVICE_ID,
        "programName" : sender[1],
        "programVersion" : "N/A"
    }
    response = requests.post(sw_send_url, data=data)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        exit(21)
else:
    sw_send_url = url + "/device/addProgram"
    data = {
        "customerId": 1L,
        "deviceId": DEVICE_ID,
        "programName": sender[0],
        "programVersion": "N/A"
    }
    response = requests.post(sw_send_url, data=data)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        exit(21)
time.sleep(0.1) #Should this be here
```

My question is on the time.sleep(). I added it to avoid sending to much information too fast but I am wondering if the sleep() method needs to be called? Or is it something that the Spring server will take care of to make sure it doesn't get overwhelmed with data? Also if it is needed what is a good amount of time to sleep the program for?